# MsBuild keeps running after build, lock folder

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'm using TFS 2013 to automate Continuous Integration build after each check in. I recently started to get the following error :

process cannot access 'myfolder' because it's being used by another process

In other words, at the start of each build, TFS try to clear source's folder, but cannot proceed, which make my build fail.

With the use of ProceddExplorer, I found out that MSBuild was was the process still having handles on my folder. So after a build, MsBuild process keeps running for some time and keeps handle on folder of the last built project of my solution.

After some research, I read that it may be caused by MSBuild running in 'node reuse' mode, so I tried to add these MSBuild arguments `/m /nr:false` to prevent MsBuild running in 'node reuse' mode, but with no success.

Note that the problem occurs when builds are running in short time lapse, after some time MSBuild process stops by himself.

Anyone ever encountered same problem ?

Comment: Is the issue occurred recently? Does it mean you don't have this issue before?

Comment: By the way,  did you change something recently?

Comment: Yeah I recently install Visual Studio Agent on my server in order to run unit test in my build process. The installtion seems to fit with the beginning of the problem

Comment: If you force MSBuild to use a single process for all projects, will the issue persist?

Comment: it seems to fix my problem, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, please upgrade your TFS2013 to the latest version TFS2013 Update5, if you haven't upgraded.

Then, try to set 'MSBuild Arguments' to `/m:1` to force MSBuild to use a single process for all projects.